# How to set timeout while doing vue-cli unit test

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I am performing vue unit through below command

```
 vue-cli-service test:unit
```

Now the problem is some unit test case need the response from the server, and usually they take much time to execute.

So i want to know how to manually set the timeout for vue-cli unit tests

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below

```
vue-cli-service test:unit --timeout, -t timeout threshold in milliseconds
```